# How to register shared NgRx effects for multiple, lazy-loaded, modules without registering at the application root?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a large, complex app with an Angular front end. Within the front end, I have several lazy-loaded modules.

One of my feature-level NgRx stores needs to be used by another feature. Both features are lazy-loaded. The only common parent is the root level of the app, where I'd prefer to minimize additional files and code.

I pulled out the NgRx store files of the first feature into their own module and import this module into that feature. This works fine. I also attempt to import the module into the other feature - which is where things break down.

The second feature successfully loads the `*.reducer.ts` file, but not the related `*.effects.ts` file. Thus, when the second feature dispatches an action, there is no loaded effect to act on the action.

If the first feature is accessed before the second feature, the effects are loaded and work as expected. The problem occurs when the second feature is loaded and used before the first feature.

**How do I get the effects file to correctly load in both features, regardless of which feature is accessed first**?

#### Example code:

*identifiers changed/removed, slightly simplified*

Shared Effects:

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, concatMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as MySharedActionsfrom './mySharedActions.actions';
import { AService} from './services/AService';

@Injectable()
export class MySharedEffects {

  mySharedEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(MySharedActions.actionOne),
      concatMap(action => {
        return this.aService.aMethod(action.prop1, action.prop2).pipe(
          map(data=> {
            if (data.succeeded) {
              return MySharedActions.actionOneSuccess({ data});
            } else {
              return MySharedActions.actionOneFailure({ error: data});
            }
          }),
          catchError(error => of(MySharedActions.actionOneFailure({ error }))),
        );
      }),
    ),
  );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private readonly aService: AService,
  ) {}
}
```

Shared Store's Module

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { MySharedEffects } from './myShared.effects';
import * as fromMyShared from './myShared.reducer';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EffectsModule.forFeature([ MySharedEffects ]),
    StoreModule.forFeature(fromMyShared.mySharedFeatureKey, MySharedEffects.reducer),
    // ...
  ],
})
export class MySharedModule {}
```

First Feature module (*everything works*)

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
// ...
import { MySharedModule } from './store/myShared.module';

@NgModule({
  entryComponents: [/*...*/],
  imports: [
    // ...,
    MySharedModule ,
    // ...,
  ],
  providers: [/*...*/],
})
export class FirstFeatureModule {}
```

Second Feature Module (*effects not loaded*)

```typescript
// ...
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MySharedModule } from '../../../first-feature/store/myShared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [/*...*/],
  entryComponents: [/*...*/],
  imports: [/*...*/, MySharedModule , /*...*/],
  exports: [/*...*/],
})
export class SecondFeatureModule{}
```

Comment: Got a solution? Add as answer if so..

Comment: No solution, as yet. But since the primarily impacted feature is just for Admins and not the general users, I've put off dealing with it until more important stuff is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample should work. Have you injected the store properly in the second feature module component? If you haven't injected the store properly, you can't dispatch the actions on that part and so your effect won't trigger.

example:

IN THE IMPORTS:

```js
import * as fromApprovals from '../state/reducers';
import * as fromAuth from '../../auth/state/reducers';
import * as fromData from '../../data/state/reducers';
```

IN THE CONSTRUCTOR:

```js
// combine your stores this way, should the second feature have it's own part of a store

constructor(private store: Store<fromApprovals.State & fromAuth.State & fromData.State>,'
```

Comment: I'll have to check that out, but it's not likely. I have a facade between my components and the NgRx store pieces. The components only call the facade. In turn the facade will dispatch actions or query selectors (possibly both in the same function). In my case, the same facade is called from both lazy-loaded modules. The facade's constructor and imports reference the reducer and action files.

Comment: Are you calling the same effect in both features to test if the issue is in the effect not being called? One issue I've had before is that I copied some actions and modified them, but forgot to change the text, which caused the effect to not be called `export const addCompany = createAction('[Companies/API] Add Company', /* <-- this part i had twice */ props<{ company: Company }>());`

Comment: It might be poor action hygiene, but the Actions are re-used, the Effects are re-used, the Reducers are re-used. The shared facade handles all this and is the interface between the components and the NgRx pieces. After compiling, that could mean duplicate definitions, one in each lazy module.

Comment: Found anything new?

Comment: Nope. But the affected component is low priority (admin functionality) and shouldn't directly affect the typical end user. Had it been the other of the two components, this would be far more important.